# Opening new window and adding local storage value in new window

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to open a new window using Javascript but also add a value to either the session storage, local storage or cookies (Preferable local storage) in that new window. Something like...

```
window.open("https://www.test.com", <ADD VALUE TO LOCAL STORAGE>);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Never going to happen unless you have access to the code at test.com

Comment: @mplungjan Why not? Don't understand why this would be a risk?

Comment: If you can insert script you could insert one that captured passwords or other credentials or sent info to your server

Comment: If you have access then simply save data in localstorage and navigate, doesn't matter site opended in new window or older one localstorage will remain same for particular website.

Comment: Ok, yeah think i'm gonna have to use a query string and then store that in the local storage when the new window loads. Shame there wasn't a short cut but better to keep it secure! Thanks guys